# where do i keep my keystore file on my apache tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I have generated a keystore file and i have an application Fortify where in its UI I need to specify the keystore path.
The syntax for specifying the file is `file:///`
I am not sure, how and where can i can put the file,so that i can add its path in my application.

The application is hosted on a tomcat server.
I tried putting the file in its `webapps` folder, but looks like that is not the right way to do it.

I also tried the access the file like `file://localhost/opt/tomcat/webapps/keystore/mykeystore.jks` but that said `file not found`
What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the file protocol syntax.

Assuming your keystore is in `/opt/tomcat/webapps/keystore/mykeystore.jks`, the way to write the file URL is `file:///opt/tomcat/webapps/keystore/mykeystore.jks` - e.g. there is no "localhost" in there, and there are three slashes.